# Dynamic PHP Array used in sendmany bitcoin command issue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, bitcoin

I have following problem with dynamic array be used in sendmany transaction in bitcoin engine, problem described in code comments.

step 1 create array
step 2 inserting values to array
step 3 print an array to check the result which is correct
step 4 sendmany (here is a problem) see below

```
<?php
//step 1 create array
$to = array();
//step 2 inserting values to array
while ( $row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($getting_allowed_users) )
{
          $to[] = array($row_users['user_bitcoin_wallet'] => $currency);
}

//step 3 print an array to check the result which is correct
print_r(array_values($to)); 

//step 4 sendmany (here is a problem)

// if I do it that way sendmany is only sending to first wallet which is indexed [0]
// I cannot to foreach as php  code structure is not allowing {} inside the command
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,$to[0]); 

//Question: How I can display all the values from my array in following place
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,ALL THE VALUES); 

//example
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,"walet1"=>0.1,"walet2"=>0.1,"walet2"=>0.1.....);
```

Comment: btw: shouldn't it be `sendMoney` instead of `sendmany` (which means something different)?

Comment: Please post an example of the contents of $to

Comment: can you show the fucntion sendmany ?

Comment: @Nimrod007: sendmany is a Bitcoin RPC command. you use it to send multiple transactions at once in order to limit fee's or make mass payments. useful for web applications that interface via jsonRPC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're bulding the **$to** array in the wrong way. You need a key-value pairs array, you can build it up this way:

```
$to[$row_users['user_bitcoin_wallet']] = $currency;
```

Then you can call **sendmany** this way:

```
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,$to);
```

Your code became:

```
<?php
//step 1 create array
$to = array();

//step 2 inserting values to array
while ( $row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($getting_allowed_users) )
{
          $to[$row_users['user_bitcoin_wallet']] = $currency;
}

//step 3 print an array to check the result which is correct
print_r(array_values($to)); 

//step 4 sendmany

$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,$to);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider spliiting that array up as too many in one request can be a bit much for the bitcoin daemon.

```
$chunks=array_chunk($to,100,true);
forach($chunks as $row) $bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,$row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paolo gave a good answer, you can find `->sendmany()` official documentation here:
[on the Mike Gogulski's bitcoin-php official Documentation](http://code.gogulski.com/bitcoin-php/class_bitcoin_client.html#a4e14526418b9263d3c3ceddcdae6d3ee)